# Ubuntu 14.04 Apache2 VirtualBox Cannot Connect from Windows Host

Tags: networking, server, windows, virtualbox, apache2

I've been through more posts than I can count at this point. I'm trying to build a web server (for internal use only -- not for public consumption) in Ubuntu/Apache running in VirtualBox (VB). I cannot connect from the host (Windows) browser to my virtual server.

I am running two NICs in VirtualBox.  The first is NAT and the second Host Only.  I now have eth0 on IP 168.192.56.1 (VB IP), eth1 on 192.168.56.101, and lo on 127.0.0.1.

I have no connections from Ubuntu.  I cannot ping my Windows host, I cannot ping 74.125.226.66 (google.com) so I've lost all my connectivity.  I also have no connections into Ubuntu.  I can neither ping nor open in FireFox on Windows.  I can ping 168.192.56.1 from Windows, but I think that may be VB answering, not my Ubuntu server.

With FireFox in Ubuntu I can connect to my server using any of the three IP addresses.

Please help or request additional information as required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that stumble across this post, I have resolved the problem.  It was due to a VirtualBox issue.  I had both NICs set to "Cable Connected" in my settings for the server in the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager.

When I checked the server as it was running, I looked in Devices > Network > Network Settings, neither one had the "Cable Connected" box checked,  Once I checked this, I was golden.  I had my Ubuntu Internet connection for updates, browsing, etc., and I was able to connect to the Ubuntu server from my Windows host.